# Why can't Scala find my typeclass instance defined implicitly in the companion object, when the typeclass is not in a dedicated source file?

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, companion-object

Please refer to the source code below.  All source code is defined in the same package.  When I define all of the code within a single source file `ShowMain.scala`, I get a compile error, however when `object ShowMain` is defined in `ShowMain.scala` and `trait Show` and `object Show` are defined in `Show.scala`, there is no compile error.

**My question:**  What is the cause for this?  What language rule have I run afoul of?

**Example code:**

```
object ShowMain {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    output("hello")
  }

  def output[A](a: A)(implicit show: Show[A]) =
    println(show.show(a))

}

trait Show[-A] {
  def show(a: A): String
}

object Show {

  implicit object StringShow extends Show[String] {
    def show(s: String) = s"[String: $s]"
  }

}
```

**Compile error:**

(ScalaIDE/Scala 2.11.2 on line containing `output("hello")`)

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - not enough arguments for method output: (implicit show: test.typeclasses.show1.Show[String])Unit. Unspecified value 
     parameter show.
    - not enough arguments for method output: (implicit show: test.typeclasses.show1.Show[String])Unit. Unspecified value 
     parameter show.
    - could not find implicit value for parameter show: test.typeclasses.show1.Show[String]
    - could not find implicit value for parameter show: test.typeclasses.show1.Show[String]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a rule that implicit has to be defined earlier in the compilation unit.

So, move object Show to the top and it compiles.

Alternatively,

```
object Show {
  //implicit object StringShow extends Show[String] {
  implicit val x: Show[String] = new Show[String] {
    def show(s: String) = s"[String: $s]"
  }
}
```

see the explanation about the type:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2731285/1296806

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up comment about the type ascription, I noticed that was the only way I could get the val to work, and was going to create a second question for that case.

Comment: Understanding the type ascription requirement answered a lot of other questions I had about the compiler being able to find my implicits.  Thanks!