# Is it better to use vals or object when providing instances of a typeclass in Scala

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

The type class pattern in Scala involves defining a trait such as:

```
trait Show[T] {
    def show(obj: T): String
}
```

Then you can define instantiations of this type class as such:

```
object Show {
    implicit val string = new Show[String] {
        def show(obj: String): String = obj
    }
    implicit object BooleanShow extends Show[Boolean] {
        def show(obj: Boolean): String = obj.toString
    }
}
```

The advantage of defining these instantiations for basic types in the companion object is that they are automatically in scope whenever the type class is concerned (roughly).

Functionally it would appear defining the instantiation as an implicit val or an implicit object does not change much.

Is there a difference? Is one way better than the other?

Comment: One difference is in exception stack trace in case typeclass can be involved. In case of `object` the name will be clearer.

Comment: @applicius I feel like that was answer worthy. Of course, I would also like to hear if there are other differences that anyone else can think of.

Comment: There is one typo in your code segment. It should be `implicit val` instead of `val implicit`.

Comment: Except this fact that with `val` anonymous class is used, with readability issue in stack trace, I don't see anything more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [val and object inside a scala class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448691/val-and-object-inside-a-scala-class)

Answer (score 1):

There is actually more than *the type names* between `val` and `object`.

You know, `object` in Scala is something like a singleton in Java.
Maybe you thought that both `string` and `BooleanShow` are in an `object` not a `class` so they have no difference, but that's not true.

They are `val` and `object` no matter what.

Try this in Scala REPL.

```
trait Show[T] {
    def show(obj: T): String
}

object Show {
    println("!! Show created")

    implicit val string = new Show[String] {
        println("!! string created")
        def show(obj: String): String = obj
    }

    implicit object BooleanShow extends Show[Boolean] {
        println("!!BooleanShow created")
        def show(obj: Boolean): String = obj.toString
    }
}
```

If only the definition is done, then no `println`s are executed afterwards, since `Show` is a singleton in effect. It's not created yet.

Next, execute `Show` in Scala REPL.

```
scala> Show
!! Show created
!! string created
res0: Show.type = Show$@35afff3b
```

You see, `println`s in `Show` and `Show.string` were called, but the one in `Show.BooleanShow` was not.

You can execute `Show.BooleanShow` next in Scala REPL.

```
scala> Show.BooleanShow
!!BooleanShow created
res1: Show.BooleanShow.type = Show$BooleanShow$@18e419c5
```

`Show.BooleanShow` was initialized at last. It is a singleton, so it is **lazy**.

Basically, your question is the same as [val and object inside a scala class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448691/val-and-object-inside-a-scala-class) except that your `val` and `object` are defined in an `object`, but the linked question tries to find differences `val` and `object` defined in a `class` and the method in `val` uses reflection (but yours uses overriding, so no reflection is involved). `implicit` basically does not make difference in what they are.

I think you already know the difference between `class` and `object`. Further information can be found in the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

Since they say always to use explicit types for implicits, prefer val over object.

Compare [Why can't Scala find my typeclass instance defined implicitly in the companion object, when the typeclass is not in a dedicated source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25468583/1296806) where it makes a difference.

Make it lazy if necessary.

Elaboration:

```
scala> trait T
defined trait T

scala> object X { implicitly[T] ; object O extends T }
<console>:8: error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: T
       object X { implicitly[T] ; object O extends T }
                            ^

scala> object X { implicitly[T] ; implicit object O extends T }
<console>:8: error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: T
       object X { implicitly[T] ; implicit object O extends T }
                            ^

scala> object X { implicitly[O.type] ; implicit object O extends T }
defined object X

scala> object X { implicitly[T] ; implicit object O extends T ; implicit def y = O }
<console>:8: error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: T
       object X { implicitly[T] ; implicit object O extends T ; implicit def y = O }
                            ^

scala> object X { implicitly[T] ; implicit object O extends T ; implicit def y: T = O }
defined object X
```

The inferred type of `O` is the singleton type `O.type`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why a val is an explicit type as opposed to object?

Comment: @UndercoverAgent Elaborated.

Answer (score 0):

With `val x = new X { }` you are creating an anonymous subclass of `X`, whereas with `object x extends X` you create a "proper" subclass. I would think that the overhead of an `object` is minimal, and as @applicius points out, it has proper name. Therefore I suggest to go for the `object` in this case.