# Why trait with implicit values should be put in the beginning of a scala file?

Tags: scala, implicit, traits

I have a scala file which uses a trait to provide implicit values:

```
class A
class B

class Service  {
  def check(implicit a:A, b:B) = println("hello")
}

object Main extends App with Dependencies {

  def run() {
    val service = new Service
    service.check
  }

}

trait Dependencies {
  implicit val a = new A
  implicit val b = new B
}
```

But it can't be compiled, the error is:

```
 error: could not find implicit value for parameter a: A
           service.check
               ^
```

But, if I put the trait `Dependencies` to the beginning of the file:

```
trait Dependencies {
  implicit val a = new A
  implicit val b = new B
}

// other code are here
```

It compiles!

Why we must put it at the beginning?

Comment: This is a greatest hits: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25468715/1296806

Comment: Even better: always provide explicit type annotations for implicit values and you don't have to worry about ridiculous compiler details like this.