# Scala Reads: How to handle Option[Map[String, Any]]

Tags: json, scala

I cannot wrap my head around why it throws an error on the following line:

```
val anyReads = Reads[Any](m => metaValueToJsValue(m))
```

Error Message:  `type mismatch; found : play.api.libs.json.JsValue required: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Any] Note: implicit value readsMap is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type`

I've pasted my code below.
Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.util._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class TempClass(
  metaValue: Option[Map[String, Any]])

object TempClass {

  val anyReads = Reads[Any](m => metaValueToJsValue(m))

  def metaValueToJsValue(m: Any): JsValue = {
    m match {
      case s: String => JsString(s)
      case n: Int => JsNumber(n): JsValue
      case n: Long => JsNumber(n): JsValue
      case n: Double => JsNumber(n): JsValue
      case n: BigDecimal => JsNumber(n): JsValue
      case b: Boolean => JsBoolean(b)
      case l: Seq[Any] => JsArray(l.map(metaValueToJsValue)): JsValue
    }
  }

  implicit val readsMap = Reads[Map[String, Any]](m => Reads.mapReads[Any](anyReads).reads(m))
  implicit val reads = Json.reads[TempClass]
}
```

Comment: You need to ascribe the type to your implicit val. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731185/why-does-this-explicit-call-of-a-scala-method-allow-it-to-be-implicitly-resolved/2731285#2731285

Comment: implicit val readsMap: Reads[Map[String, Any]] = Reads[Map[String, Any]](m => Reads.mapReads[Any](anyReads).reads(m))
implicit val reads: Reads[TempClass] = Json.reads[TempClass]
The above has no effect though :/ Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are doing something really wrong here.

> val anyReads = Reads[Any](m => metaValueToJsValue(m))

Reads takes as argument a function which accepts `JsValue` and returns `JsResult[A]` but you are passing a function which takes Any and return JsValue.

So the signature of `def metaValueToJsValue(m: Any): JsValue = {` should be like this

```
def metaValueToJsValue(m: JsValue): JsResult[Any] = {
```

NOTE: Generally frameworks doesn't provide default serializers for Polymorphic Maps (Map[String, Any]) because the Any can again be Maps/Lists and can go to any level. So application should have knowledge of the incoming JSON structure. In the below code i have made an assumption of one level ie, Json attribute values themselves can't be Json objects/arrays

Please refer to the code below:

```
object TempClass {

    implicit val readsMap = Reads[Map[String, Any]](m => Reads.mapReads[Any](anyReads).reads(m))
    implicit val reads = Json.reads[TempClass]
    val anyReads = Reads[Any](m => metaValueToJsValue(m))

    def metaValueToJsValue(m: JsValue): JsResult[Any] = {
      m match {
        case JsObject(m) => {
          val m1 = m.map(f => (f._1, convert(f._2))).toMap
          JsSuccess(m1)
        }
        case JsString(s) => JsSuccess(s)
        case JsNumber(n) => JsSuccess(n)
        case JsBoolean(b) => JsSuccess(b)
        case JsArray(arr) => {
          val list = arr.map(convert)
          JsSuccess(list)
        }
      }
    }

    def convert(m: JsValue): Any = {
      m match {
        case JsString(s) => s
        case JsNumber(n) => n
        case JsBoolean(b) => b
      }
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val json = """{"metaValue" : {"name":"John", "age":30}}"""
      val tmpClass = Json.parse(json).as[TempClass]
      println(tmpClass)
    }

  }
```

Comment: Sorry but could you please explain the following to me? What is the purpose of the main method in the Object, also why am I no longer able to parse this class? val tempClass = Json.parse(response.body).as[TempClass]

Comment: I added main method just to show how to parse TempClass from a json string. You can remove that method. Also you need to enhance this code by matching more cases like JsNull, JsUndefined etc in the methods.

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that it's better to have the JsObject last otherwise everything can be matched as a JsObject. Also there isn't a need for the convert. A better solution (though incomplete) is as follows:

```
object ContractDetails {
  implicit val readsMap = Reads[Map[String, Any]](m => Reads.mapReads[Any](anyReads).reads(m))
  implicit val reads = Json.reads[ContractDetails]
  val anyReads = Reads[Any](m => metaValueToJsValue(m))

  def metaValueToJsValue(m: JsValue): JsResult[Any] = {
    m match {
      case JsBoolean(b) => JsSuccess(b)
      case JsNumber(n) => JsSuccess(n)
      case JsString(s) => JsSuccess(s)
      case JsArray(arr) => {
        val list = arr.map(metaValueToJsValue)
        JsSuccess(list)
      }
      case JsNull => JsSuccess(null)
      //case x => JsFailure(x.toString())
      case JsObject(m) => {
        val m1 = m.map(f => (f._1, metaValueToJsValue(f._2))).toMap
        JsSuccess(m1)
      }
    }
  }
```