# Implicit parameter need Type annotation to compile

Tags: scala, implicit

Here is my test code :

```
object ImplicitTest {
  import JoesPrefs._
  Greeter.greet("Joe") // could not find implicit value for parameter prompt: 
}
class PreferredPrompt(val preference: String)

object JoesPrefs {
  implicit val prompt = new PreferredPrompt("Yes, master> ")
}
object Greeter {
  def greet(name: String)(implicit prompt: PreferredPrompt) = {
    println("Welcome, " + name + ". The system is ready.")
    println(prompt.preference)
  }
}
```

I use scala 2.11.12, don't know why this implicit not work until  add type annotation to val :

```
object JoesPrefs {
  implicit val prompt: PreferredPrompt  = new PreferredPrompt("Yes, master> ")
}
```

Comment: Anyways an implicit value should always have an explicit type annotation.

Comment: I think it's a good practice but not a must ?

Comment: In some cases, it is really needed. In other cases, it helps. And in a few cases, it is not possible to do.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438750/how-does-scala-use-explicit-types-when-resolving-implicits#comment52747717_32438750 and

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Scala use explicit types when resolving implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438750/how-does-scala-use-explicit-types-when-resolving-implicits)

Comment: Yeah, it's so related I voted to close here ^^ good find :-)

Comment: I think this question is more simple and direct for people to find the similar problem, though the answer you mention is related to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the exact internal are a bit wild, but basically it boils down to the compilation order of the code.
When you add the type annotation, the val is "compiled and put in scope" sooner than when you do not, and it becomes available to resolve in ImplicitTest.

Funnily (at least for me ^^), you can also move ImplicitTest to be on a line of code after the JoesPref object (or move it to its own file), it will compile without the type annotation.

Comment: yes, it act like you told. Do you know anywhere mentioning about this situation?

Comment: There's this comment by the language creator : https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/801#issuecomment-292352399